# Clarification on mixture of pdf and mixture of cdf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

I have a question on how to define [mixture distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Finite_and_countable_mixtures) for continuous random variables. In short, what I'm confused about is whether they can be **equivalently** written using the cdf (cumulative distribution function) or the pdf (probability density function).

Let me explain my doubt with an example.

---

Let $Y,X,W$ be real-valued random variables, respectively with supports denoted by $\mathcal{Y},\mathcal{X},\mathcal{W}$.

**(A1)** Assume that $\mathcal{X},\mathcal{W}$ are finite.

**(A2)** Assume that $Y$ is a continuous random variable, with well defined pdf.

---

Consider now the pdf $f(\cdot)$ of $Y$  evaluated at $y\in \mathcal{Y}$:

$$f(y)=\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X},w\in \mathcal{W}} f(y,x,w)=\overbrace{\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X},w\in \mathcal{W}} \overbrace{p(x,w)}^{\text{Mixing weight}}\times \overbrace{f(y| X=x, W=w)}^{\text{Mixing density}}}^{\text{Finite mixture}}
$$
where $p(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the probability mass function of $(X,W)$.

It seems to me that the **pdf** of $Y$ can be written as a finite mixture (assuming that $f(y|X=x, W=w)$ is well-defined at each $x\in \mathcal{X}, w\in \mathcal{W}$).

I don't think though that the same relation holds for the **cdf** of $Y$. In other words, let $F(\cdot)$ denote the cdf of $Y$; I think that 
$$
F(y)\neq \sum_{x\in \mathcal{X},w\in \mathcal{W}} p(x,w)\times F(y| X=x, W=w)
$$

Therefore, I would like you help to understand the following:

- Can we write $F(\cdot)$ as a mixture?
- If yes, using which weights and what is the relation of those weights with the weights $\{p(x,w)\}_{x,w}$ used above?
- If not, why do I have the impression that in the stat literature mixtures are flexibly defined using cdf or pdf, as in this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Finite_and_countable_mixtures) article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any Borel set $B$ we can write:$$P(Y\in B)=\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X},w\in \mathcal{W}}P(X=x,W=w)P(Y\in B\mid X=x,W=w)=\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X},w\in \mathcal{W}}p(x,w)P_{x,w}(B)$$

Doing so for $B=(-\infty,y]$ we find something like:

$$F_Y(y)=\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X},w\in \mathcal{W}}p(x,w)F_{x,w}(y)$$where every $F_{x,w}$ can be recognized as a CDF.

Comment: Thanks. From your claim, I understand that I can write BOTH (1) $f(y)=\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}, w\in \mathcal{W}} p(x,w) f(y|X=x, W=w)$ (i.e., the mixture with the pdf) and (2)  $F(y)=\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}, w\in \mathcal{W}} p(x,w) F(y|X=x, W=w)$ (i.e., the mixture with the cdf). Notice that (1) and (2) use the same mixing weights. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.